# Clear form and redirect back to index

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form which takes input and enters it into the database. This is fine and working perfectly, except I have run into an issue with clearing the form. In Wamp it merely takes me to contactForm.php, which is a blank page. I have been trying to find a way of redirecting the user back to index.php and clearing the form. From searching around I have tried a couple of things (perhaps incorrectly) including putting this at the end of my php:

```
header('Location: http://stackoverflow.com');
```

and I also tried to write a JS function to do it

```
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="clearForm();"></p>
```

js

```
function clearForm(){
    alert("Thanks, we will be in touch shortly");
    document.getElementById("contactForm").reset();
}
```

Comment: you could use jquery for that.

Comment: Why did the PHP way not work for you?

Comment: Not sure. I just got the same result - entry into db and blank page. I have just tried the method suggested below and got the same result. I tried adding an alert on document ready but not seeing it so I may have an issue with my Wamp server or something. Obviously I will have to make sure that is working correctly first.

Comment: OK so my paths were a little bit messed up. The javascript console told me Wamp was not finding my js file, images etc. Anyway, once I sorted that I put the following code at the end of my PHP script and it now works. Thanks for your input.                                 echo  "<script> alert('Thanks, we will be in touch shortly');
    window.location.href='index.php#contact-bg';
    </script>";

Answer (score 1):

```
function clearForm(){
      alert("Thanks, we will be in touch shortly");
      window.location=ur_url_here;
}
```

When you got redirect form will automatically reset

Answer (score 0):

```
function clearForm(){
      alert("Thanks, we will be in touch shortly");
      window.location='http://stackoverflow.com';
}
```

There is no need to clear the form specifically, unless you are using some other element to save the details the form will be forgotten when you move to a new page.

Answer (score 0):

```
function clearForm() {
    alert("Thanks, we will be in touch shortly");
    window.location='http://stackoverflow.com';
}
```

Comment: Please try to flesh out your answer a bit more. Just posting a code block without any explanation or context is not good. In its current state your answer might not be of any use to people looking for an answer to this question in the future.